# How can I apply a function to a dataframe which needs a row index in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to use survey data from ipums to get the average number of people who are unemployed in two successive periods. I wrote a function that uses an index and a dataframe as input,

```
def u1(x,df):
if df.loc[x]['LABFORCE']==2 and df.loc[x]['CPSIDP']==df.loc[x+1]['CPSIDP']:
    if df.loc[x]['EMPSTAT']==21 or df.loc[x]['EMPSTAT']==22:
        return True
else: 
    return False
```

where `x` is the index and `df` is the dataframe. `CPSIDP` identifies the survey respondent, `LABFORCE` checks the respondent is in the labor force and `EMPSTAT` is what I need to use to check the employment status of the respondent.

And then I planned to use `apply` as

```
result= df.apply(u1, axis=1)
```

It is not clear what arguments I should pass in my function (and please let me know if this approach is just philosophically wrong). Passing a number or a variable for the index gives me a 'bool' object is not callable error.

The smallest dataframe subset that generates the error (left most column is the number of the observation, it is the `x` I need to pass through `u1`):

```
          YEAR  MONTH          CPSIDP  EMPSTAT  LABFORCE
15285896  2018      7  20180707096701       10         2
15285926  2018      7  20180707098301       10         2
15285927  2018      7  20180707098302       10         2
15285928  2018      7  20180707098303        0         0
15285929  2018      7  20180707098304        0         0
15285930  2018      7  20180707098305       10         2
15286095  2018      7  20180707108203       21         2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC it would be more efficient to create a `boolean` `Series` using the logic from your function.

Here `&` is the `AND` operator.

```
result = (df['LABFORCE'].eq(2) & 
           df['CPSIDP'].eq(df['CPSIDP'].shift()) & 
           df['EMPSTAT'].isin([21,22]))

result

15285896    False
15285926    False
15285927    False
15285928    False
15285929    False
15285930    False
15286095    False
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked and it was much faster than the `for x` loop I tried (which took over an hour). If you don't mind, can you tell me if I wanted to stick to the `df.apply()` approach what would I need to do? Or was it just too cumbersome/ impossible?

Comment: If you were using `DataFrame.apply` you'd have to do something like `df.apply(lambda row: u1(row.index, row), axis=1)`. `apply` is generally not recommended though if a vectorized solution exists.